# Seifert surfaces in Riemannian manifolds?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, knot-theory

Does there exist an equivalent to Seifert surfaces for other Riemannian manifolds than $\mathbb{R}^3$? More precisely:

> Let $M$ be a simply-connected Riemannian manifolds and $K \subset M$ a (tame) knot. Does there exist a surface $\Sigma$ embedded into $M$ satisfying $\partial \Sigma=K$?

I am also interested in particular cases if they exist (other than $\mathbb{S}^3$ of course).

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your question: if you mean a closed connected manifold, then simply-connectedness just means it is $S^3$. I am also not quite sure what is the need for Riemannianness, there is a simple rule: whenever your knot is nullhomologous, it bounds a surface. So in particular, in integral homology spheres there are Seifert surfaces.

Comment: In my question, $M$ is not necessarily three-dimensional. Can you tell me more about the simple rule you mention? It could be able to answer my question.

Comment: @Fyodor: Is that always true that the knot can be bounded by an embedded one if it is nulhomologous?

Comment: It is certainly true in 3 dimensions...I don't know what happens in higher dimensions, but certainly if a knot is not null-homologous, it cannot bound a surface. On the other hand, I would guess that there is no real 1-dimensional knottedness in manifolds of dimensions higher than 3: there are only trivial (everything is smooth) knots in spheres of codimension at least two. So I would guess all the 'knottedness' in other manifolds is just the manifestation of different elements of the fundamental group. And in simply-connected manifolds I wouldn't expect to have non-trivial knots.

Comment: Every smooth homologically trivial knot bounds an embedded surface (in all dimensions). It is actually easier in higher dimensions than in dimension 3, just take a generic smooth map whose boundary is the given curve. In dimension more than 4 the generic map will be an embedding. In dimension 4 it will have finitely many self intersections, at which you can replace the double points by the self connected sum of the immersed surface.

Comment: I only know generic maps from Hirsch's book, *Differential topology*, but he only considers the case of manifolds without boundary I think. Also, probably I will need more information about the dimension 4. Do you have references?

Comment: Unfortunatly, the case of dimension 3 lies on Poincaré's conjecture, in order to justify that it is sufficient to consider Seifert surfaces in $\mathbb{S}^3$. It does not sound really satisfying.

Comment: Perhaps I am coming into this conversation too late, but are you assuming codimension 2 knots?  Also, in general, Rolfsen's *Knots and Links* covers higher dimensional Seifert surfaces in chapter 5.